# how to store file path in Solr when using TikaEntityProcessor

Tags: solr, apache-tika, dataimporthandler

I am using DIH to index local file system. But the file path, size and lastmodified field were not stored. in the schema.xml I defined:

```
 <fields>
   <field name="title" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="author" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <!--<field name="text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    liang added-->
   <field name="path" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="size" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="lastmodified" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 </fields>
```

And also defined tika-data-config.xml:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource name="bin" type="BinFileDataSource" />
    <document>
        <entity name="f" dataSource="null" rootEntity="false"
            processor="FileListEntityProcessor"
            baseDir="E:/my_project/ecmkit/infotouch" 
            fileName=".*\.(DOC)|(PDF)|(pdf)|(doc)|(docx)|(ppt)" onError="skip"
            recursive="true">
            <entity name="tika-test" dataSource="bin" processor="TikaEntityProcessor"
            url="${f.fileAbsolutePath}" format="text" onError="skip">
                <field column="Author" name="author" meta="true"/>
                <field column="title" name="title" meta="true"/>
                <!--
                <field column="text" name="text"/> -->
                <field column="fileAbsolutePath" name="path" />
                <field column="fileSize" name="size" />
                <field column="fileLastModified" name="lastmodified" />
            </entity>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

The Solr version is 3.5. any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Asked on the solr mailing list: http://www.mail-archive.com/solr-user@lucene.apache.org/msg64225.html . I replied there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those data don't come from the Tika metadata, so you should move them to the `FileListEntityProcessor` entity like this:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource name="bin" type="BinFileDataSource" />
    <document>
        <entity name="f" dataSource="null" rootEntity="false"
            processor="FileListEntityProcessor"
            baseDir="/home/luca/Documents" 
            fileName=".*\.(DOC)|(PDF)|(pdf)|(doc)|(docx)|(ppt)" onError="skip"
            recursive="true">

            <field column="fileAbsolutePath" name="path" />
            <field column="fileSize" name="size" />
            <field column="fileLastModified" name="lastmodified" />

            <entity name="tika-test" dataSource="bin" processor="TikaEntityProcessor"
            url="${f.fileAbsolutePath}" format="text" onError="skip">
                <field column="Author" name="author" meta="true"/>
                <field column="title" name="title" meta="true"/>
                <!--<field column="text" />-->          
            </entity>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare this fields in DIH config, just define them in schema.xml:

```
<field name="fileAbsolutePath" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" />
<field name="file"             type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" />
<field name="fileLastModified" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" />
```

They are filled automatically (tested in solr 4.6) based on `FileListEntityProcessor`.