# solr: How to store relative path when using FileListEntityProcessor

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I use FileListEntityProcessor to index a local directory.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9883699/how-to-store-file-path-in-solr-when-using-tikaentityprocessor) solution works but I don't want to store the absolute path. Instead I'd like to stored the path relative to baseDir.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the relative path, you can use [ScriptTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#ScriptTransformer) to use the absolute path and modify it to generate a new field for relative path. e.g.

```
<dataConfig>
        <script><![CDATA[
                function retrieveRelativePath(row)    {
                    var absolutePath = row.get('absolutePath');
                    // Curtail to Relative path
                    var relativePath = absolutePath.something();
                    row.put('relativePath', relativePath);
                    return row;
                }
        ]]></script>
        <document>
                <entity name="e" pk="id" transformer="script:retrieveRelativePath" query="select * from X">
                ....
                </entity>
        </document>
</dataConfig>
```